# Empty text field error: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, numberformatexception

I'm working on a `JFrame` and my purpose is calculating regression analysis with 26 variables x and y.  But I have a problem with text field. For example; if the user have 10 variables x and y after enter the values the other text fields remains blank because of this frame gives an error like:

```
Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Let me take a look into my crystal ball... No, it's all foggy. You will have to provide some more details like code that relates to the problem. Also take a look at this help section about [asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with hotzst ask your questions better. However use a little google-fu and you can see exactly what your error is pointing to. java.lang.NumberFormatException. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html

Comment: You pass an empty string to Integer.parseInt() or a similar method. Please post at least the full stack trace.

Comment: Any combination of `JTextField` & `NumberFormatException` screams **use a `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel` instead!**

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in such a case would be to not run the code if the string is empty.

Since you have not provided any code, I cannot be precise, but probably this should work:

```
if(str.trim().length()>0)
{
    //To convert it into a number.
}else{
    //To do when it is empty.
}
```